# Calling setInterval multiple times then Clearing interval , polling not stopped

Tags: javascript, setinterval, polling

As my loop is so fast, the intervals are overlapping and not able to stop one timerId. here is my code:

```
data = ['115536', '117202']; // BARCODES AVAILABLE ON A4 SHEET //

var scan_delay = 500; // USER AVG SCANNING SPEED PER BARCODE //
var timerId;

var scannedItemsList = []; // ITEMS WHICH ARE SCANNED BY SEEING A4 SHEET BY THE USER //
var tableDataList = []; // TO SHOW DATA WHICH WE GOT FROM API //
```

[Jbin](https://jsbin.com/dihesat/1/edit?js,console)

```js
try {
var data = ['115536', '117202']; // BARCODES AVAILABLE ON A4 SHEET //

var scan_delay = 500; // USER AVG SCANNING SPEED PER BARCODE //
var timerId;

var scannedItemsList = []; // ITEMS WHICH ARE SCANNED BY SEEING A4 SHEET BY THE USER //
var tableDataList = []; // TO SHOW DATA WHICH WE GOT FROM API //



execute(data);

function execute(data) {
    var i = 0;
    scanSimulatorWithADelay(data, i);
}

function scanSimulatorWithADelay(data, i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        getJobDetailsByCallingAPI(data[i], i);
        i++;

        if (data.length > i) {
            scanSimulatorWithADelay(data, i);
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, scan_delay);
}

function getJobDetailsByCallingAPI(jobNumber, index) {

    scannedItemsList.push(jobNumber);

    //poll_for_jobs_count_which_are_scanned_but_waiting_to_add_to_table
    startPolling();

    //Simulate API to get response after every 3 seconds//
    var apiDelay = (index + 1) * 3000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('API CALLED AT ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        CallTheAPI(jobNumber);
    }, apiDelay);

}

function CallTheAPI(jobNumber) {
    console.log("JOB NO " + jobNumber + " API response Recd");
    tableDataList.push(jobNumber);

}

function startPolling() {
    var pollStatus = '';
    timerId = setInterval(() => {
        debugger;
        console.log('timerId when starting interval ' + timerId);
        var jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded = jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoadedStill();
        console.log("$$$$$$ jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded = " + jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded.length);
        if (jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded.length === 0) {
            console.log("@@@ Inteval Cleared @@@ " + timerId);

            //CLEAR TIMER
            clearInterval(timerId);

        } else {
            pollStatus = 'Polling inprogress and the pollID ' + timerId;
        }
        console.log('####' + pollStatus);
    }, 2000);

}

function jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoadedStill() {
    let stillLoadingJobs = [];

    scannedItemsList.forEach(scannedItemsListJobNumber => {
        let foundJobInsideTable = false;
        if (scannedItemsListJobNumber) {
            foundJobInsideTable = tableDataList.indexOf(scannedItemsListJobNumber) > -1;
            if (!foundJobInsideTable) {
                stillLoadingJobs.push(scannedItemsListJobNumber);
            }
        }

    }); // End of scannedItemsList forEach loop 

    if (stillLoadingJobs.length > 0) {
        return stillLoadingJobs;
    }

    return [];
}
} catch (error) { throw error; }
```

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `setInterval()`. Use `setTimeout()` instead, and call it recursively once the function has executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `timer_id` variable is on the global scope and hence overwritten every time you call `startPolling`.

So when you'll call `clearInterval(timer_id)`, `timer_id` will be the id of the last  `setInterval`, and the first one will keep running endlessly.

Simply add a `var` in your `startPolling` function so that `timer_id` be scoped correctly, and that it doesn't get overwritten by next call.

```js
try {var data = ['115536', '117202'];

var scan_delay = 500;
// remove this one
//var timerId;

var scannedItemsList = [];  
var tableDataList = []; 



execute(data);

function execute(data) {
  var i = 0;
  scanSimulatorWithADelay(data, i);
}

function scanSimulatorWithADelay(data, i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    getJobDetailsByCallingAPI(data[i], i);
    i++;

    if (data.length > i) {
      scanSimulatorWithADelay(data, i);
    } else {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, scan_delay);
}

function getJobDetailsByCallingAPI(jobNumber, index) {

  scannedItemsList.push(jobNumber);

  //poll_for_jobs_count_which_are_scanned_but_waiting_to_add_to_table
  startPolling();

  //Simulate API to get response after every 3 seconds//
  var apiDelay = (index + 1) * 3000;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('API CALLED AT ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
    CallTheAPI(jobNumber);
  }, apiDelay) ;

}

function CallTheAPI(jobNumber) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
      console.log("JOB NO " + jobNumber + " API response Recd");
                    tableDataList.push(jobNumber);
    }
  });

}

function startPolling() {
  var pollStatus = '';
/////////
///HERE
/////////
// Declare timerId in startPolling scope
/////////
  var timerId = setInterval(() => {
    debugger;
    console.log('timerId when starting interval '+ timerId);
    var jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded = jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoadedStill();
    console.log("$$$$$$ jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded = "+ jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded.length);
    if (jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoaded.length === 0) {
      console.log("@@@ Inteval Cleared @@@ "+ timerId);

      //CLEAR TIMER
      clearInterval(timerId);
      
    } else {
      pollStatus = 'Polling inprogress and the pollID ' + timerId;
    }
    console.log('####' + pollStatus);
  }, 2000);

}

function jobsWhichAreScannedButNotLoadedStill() {
  let stillLoadingJobs = [];

  scannedItemsList.forEach(scannedItemsListJobNumber => {
    let foundJobInsideTable = false;
    if (scannedItemsListJobNumber) {
      foundJobInsideTable = tableDataList.indexOf(scannedItemsListJobNumber) > -1;
      if (!foundJobInsideTable) {
        stillLoadingJobs.push(scannedItemsListJobNumber);
      }
    }

  }); // End of scannedItemsList forEach loop 

  if (stillLoadingJobs.length > 0) {
    return stillLoadingJobs;
  }

  return [];
}
} catch (error) { throw error; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If i am navigating to another page, still poller is executing.

Comment: @Abhi what do you mean? Here? Runnin the Snippet in this answer?

Comment: I inserted my code in scan.html and scanned 500 job numbers and when the logic is still executing I am navigating to search.html . and when I check the console. Still the polling is happening. As my appication is single page and I am using destroy method of scan.html still not stopping. I am saving all my pollids in a list and when user navigate from scan.html, destroy method will be fired and inside the destroy method I am looping the pollIds which were saved and calling clearInterval(pillId). Still no luck

Comment: @Abhi no that is not clear at all. Code of one page will simply stop executing when you close the document. I really don't know what you are talking about, and I fear I don't have the time to dig it futher. This community answer was to lead you to the way to fix your typo/brain-fart.

Comment: "Code of one page will simply stop executing when you close the document", this statement is wrong in single page application. Polling wont stop without stopping explicitly even though you navigate to another page. Yes, I know this "This community answer was to lead you to the way to fix your typo/brain-fart" .The issue is happening in my application thats why I am asking.